# How to get all column values from csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a table in .csv which contains some random messages:

```
id,msg
2,start
1,bot
1,run
2,san
```

I want to get only rows which match certain condition. I managed to do that, but I want to get all cell values of column - msg which match condition.

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('msgs.csv')

# if id==2 and msg contains letter 'a'
p = df[(df['id'] == 2) & (df['msg'].str.contains('a'))]
print(p)

for row in p:
    print(p.iloc[0]['msg'])
```

When I `print(p)` my result (which is good) is:

```
           id msg
1          2  start
5          2    san
```

And I want to have output like this :

```
start
san
```

But when I try to do it with `iloc` I get only first cell value:

```
start
start
```

Probably the solution is easy but I don't know how to get it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do this:

```
for x in p['msg'].values:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always iterate through each row in the csv like this:

```
for row_number,id,msg in p:
    print(row-number,id,msg)
```

This will get you the following result:

```
1 2  start
5 2  san
```

So if you want just the 'msg' then print this:

```
for row_number,id,msg in p:
    print(msg)
```

Hope this helps!